# Intercept Http Endpoint Exception [Mule ESB]

Tags: exception, mule, interceptor

I'am using Mule 3.3.0 CE and I would have a custom behaviour when an exception is thrown in an http outbound endpoint (i.e when I get a Connection Refused Exception or Connection Timeout Exception). Let's assume that I have this scenario: a SOAP Component and a Http Outbound Endpoint that realize together a cxf service client and let's assume that I can't use any exception strategy. 
I would write an Interceptor which intercept the http exception (i.e Connection Refused) and in which I can write a custon behaviour (i.e send the message in a queue).

I need of an interceptor that intercept che http exception and no a SOAP Fault (that could be intercepted with a SOAPFaultInterceptor).

How can I realize this model?

Thank you all for any help

Comment: Sorry, if you con not help me with the issue explained above, could anyone help me about how to intercept the org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault class in order to customize its behaviour?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used a custom interceptor ( component) just before the Http component and I extended the AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor that gives to me the possibility to work before, after and during the component is processing the message. 
With this perspective, I implemented the *last* method. This method's sign contains a boolean value that is setted is an exception occurred. In this way I can leverage this method to handle any kind of exceptions that is related to Http Component.